# How to Draw a Rectangle in Paper.js?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, paperjs

I cannot get Paper.js to draw a rectangle. I've followed the tutorial but nothing seems to be working. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code below?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<!--load paper.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/node_modules/paper/dist/paper-core.js"></script>

<!--drawing script-->
<script type="text/javascript" canvas="canvas">
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    paper.setup(canvas);

    var meterStart = new paper.Point(5,5);
    var meterSize = new paper.Size(40, 720);
    var meter = new paper.Rectangle(meterStart, meterSize);
    meter.strokeColor = 'black';
    paper.view.draw();

    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas" height="750px" width="600px"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you are using doesn't actually draw out the rectangle correctly. Instead, it just defines the rectangle object.

Here's the correct way to draw a rectangle: https://jsbin.com/niwegobanu/edit?html,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<!--load paper.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.10.2/paper-full.js"></script>

</head>

<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(50, 50), new Point(150, 100));
    var path = new Path.Rectangle(rectangle);
    path.fillColor = '#e9e9ff';
    path.selected = true;
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's what I needed to know. Thanks!

Comment: More information can be found over here: http://paperjs.org/tutorials/paths/creating-predefined-shapes/

Please leave an upvote to this post if you found this to be helpful.